# Get coordinates around

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, coordinates

I have dashboard of x,y coordinates like this one:

[image]

now let's say I am on `4,4` and I want to get array of objects containing x,y of every coord aroung 4,4 in range of 2.

So the output array of object would be something like

```
[{x: 2, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 4, y: 2}, {x: 5, y: 2}, {x: 6, y: 2}, ...]
```

[image]

(now I see that x,y on images are the other way around sorry, mistake)

I can get x like this:

```
const currentCoord = { x: 4, y: 4 };
const range = 2;
const coordsAround = [];

for(let i = 0; i < range * 2; i++) {
  coordsAround.push({x: currentCoord.x - range + i, y: currentCoord.y})
}

console.log(coordsAround)
```

but this is far from solution. So what is best approach to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through both `x` and `y` values - and use `<=` to get to the range you want:

```js
const currentCoord = { x: 4, y: 4 };
const range = 2;
const coordsAround = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= range * 2; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j <= range * 2; j++) {
    coordsAround.push({ x: currentCoord.x - range + j, y: currentCoord.y - range + i });
  }
}

console.log(coordsAround);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: you might want to watch out for edge cases eg: starting at `0, 0` will give you negative numbers

Comment: Yes @NickParsons, but I'm not sure whether the OP wants that or not (plane geometry/coordinates *always* ends in negatives one way or another).

Comment: Yes I can not get negative coordinates but I just added `if(currentCoord.x - range + j >= 0 && currentCoord.y - range + i >= 0) {` within the inner loop and it seems to be working just fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xodoWM?editors=0010

Comment: Glad to see I helped @dopeCode!